# Delete certain phrases expression

Tags: notepad++

I want to turn many entries like this

```
"id" : "john.doe.newest:/path/to/file.zip",
"id" : "sue.robins.newest:/path/to/file.zip",
"id" : "jack.brown.newest:/path/to/file.zip",
```

into

```
"id" : "path/to/file.zip",
```

So I just need to delete that first bit. I also need to make sure it will only delete the text if it includes `.newest` since there are also entries like this that I do not want changed:

```
"john.doe.275:/path/to/file.zip,
```

I messed with it for an hour and just couldn't figure it out.

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `:\h*[^\s:]+\.newest`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
:               # colon
\h*             # 0 or more horizontal spaces
[^\s:]+         # 1 or more any character that is not space or colon
\.newest        # literally .newest
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that didn't quite work but I managed to get it to work with a slight change: "\h*[^\s:]+\.newest:/

Comment: @John: Could you give examples that didn't work?